# Android How to create dotted line using shape tag?

Tags: android

How to create dotted line in blue square using shape tag?
I need to create button like below.

[image]

Do you have any nice idea?

I used stroke to create dotted line, but no padding outside of the dotted line.

```
    <stroke
        android:color="#C7B299"
        android:dashWidth="10px"
        android:dashGap="10px"
        android:width="1dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:-

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="your background color"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="Hello dashed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="dotted drawable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

this is dotted drawable :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/white"
        android:dashWidth="8dp"
        android:dashGap="4dp"/>


</shape>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for saving my three hour.

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">
<stroke
    android:dashGap="3dp"
    android:dashWidth="3dp"
    android:color="@color/color_red"
    android:width="1dp"/>
<size android:height="1dp"/>
```

you can try it use above code

Answer (score 0):

Check out to create a shape and use that as a background or boarder

the shape could be a line and have attributes.

```
android:dashWidth="x"
android:dashGap="x"
```